# Is this possible specific key to change specific language?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I am using a Japanese keyboard layout MacBook.

and now I am using Right Command key as [F18] for [Select next input source in menu]

[image]

and Japanese layout MacBook has keys to change language directly to English and Japanese.

[image]

So, I would like to use Right Command key to change input source to another Language(Korean)?

Is this possible to change only language?

I don't want to change keyboard layout.